# Tensorflow + google ml-engne local predict: How CSV quotes should be processed?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I have trained a CNN model for predicting 0/1 values and using google ml-engine local predict for testing it. My test file contains 2 lines:

```
some text
"some text"
```

and I know that this should give me 1 and 1 as predicted result. But output is 1 and 0. So double quotes matter for some reason.
While training pandas.read_csv is used for vocabulary creation.

```
pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, sep=',', names=['source', 'title'],encoding='utf-8', na_filter=False,engine='python')
```

For prediction following command is used:

```
gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=.... --text-instances=... --format=json
```

Am I missing some parameter while reading csv for training or is this google ml-engine's issue?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the graph you exported contains a `decode_csv` op to read inputs. How quotes are handled will depend on the setting to the parameter `use_quote_delim`. To illustrate, consider the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

data = ['some text', '"some text"']
with tf.Session() as sess:
  use_delim = tf.decode_csv(data, [['']], use_quote_delim=True)
  dont = tf.decode_csv(data, [['']], use_quote_delim=False)
  out = sess.run([use_delim, dont])
  print("use", out[0])
  print("dont", out[1])

>>> ('use', [array(['some text', 'some text'], dtype=object)])
>>> ('dont', [array(['some text', '"some text"'], dtype=object)])
```

To get the behavior you are expecting, you want your exported model to set `use_quote_delim=True` (which is the default).

Comment: use_quote_delim was not used, so it was true by default. Setting it explicitly does not help as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you using pandas in your input function or are you using tf.decode_csv?

In your gcloud prediction call, you are setting the input format to json. Did you mean to set it to CSV?